# Delphi TComboBox disable highlight (focused)

Tags: delphi, tcombobox

After open form item in TCombobox is highlighted (Blue backgrond on text).

Is it possible disable that.

[image]

Tnx all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put this message into `OnEnter` event of `TCombobox` object:

```
// Suppose the combobox control name is ComboBox
procedure TMainForm.ComboBoxEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PostMessage(ComboBox.Handle, CB_SETEDITSEL, Cardinal(-1), 0);
end;
```